# in iOS 11.3 update screen an extra 2 is appearing with black color on iPhone 8?

Tags: iphone, ios, hardware, software-update

When I was updating my iPhone 8 to iOS 11.3 I went to the Software Update screen and there I noticed an extra "2" appearing in black letter after the link 
 image :-

[image]

after HT1222 an extra 2 in black font is there. It appears like this

> HT1222**2**

I think there is some problem there. Should I update?